# Gitlab export: bundle and rake not found

Tags: ubuntu, export, gitlab

I've installed GitLab from source (Ubuntu 16.04). So i tried following command to backup my gitlab system:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production
```

I got the following error:

```
sudo: bundle: command not found
```

After I fixed that, I got the following additional error:

```
bundler: command not found: rake
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work with the following command:

```
sudo -u git -H /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle exec /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: doesn't work on debian 12